# How to execute jasmine tests for node modules from grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jasmine

I want to run some Jasmine 2.x tests for node.js modules in a Grunt build. My setup looks like this:

**src/foo.js**

```
exports.bar = 23;
```

**spec/foo.spec.js**

```
var foo = require("../src/foo.js");

define("foo", function() {
  it("exports bar as 23", function() {
    expect(foo.bar).toBe(23);
  });
});
```

With [grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine) the node module system is not available and I get

```
>> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require at
>> spec/foo.spec.js:1
```

There is [grunt-jasmine-node](https://github.com/jasmine-contrib/grunt-jasmine-node/), but it depends on [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) which is unmaintained and includes Jasmine 1.3.1, so this is not an option.

Jasmine [supports node.js out of the box](https://jasmine.github.io/2.3/node.html), by including a file `jasmine.json` in the `spec` directory, I can run the tests with the `jasmine` cli. Is there any *clean* way to run the same tests from grunt as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [grunt-exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec), which just executes the value as if typed on the command line:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        exec: {
            jasmine: "jasmine"
        },

        env: {
            test: {
                NODE_ENV: "test"
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-exec");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-env");

    grunt.registerTask("test", [
        "env:test",
        "exec:jasmine"
    ]);
};
```

This will allow you to keep jasmine up to date as well as use it with other grunt tasks.

Comment: Perfect, that works. When a test fails, the jasmine process exits with an error code that in turn lets the grunt build fail.